# Specify that protractor should use my manually downloaded chromedriver

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor

For security reasons, selenium aren't allowed to download the chromedriver when running `webdriver-manager update`

I have manually downloaded the chromedriver (v. 2.27) for protractor and placed it in the `node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium`  folder:

[image]

However when I try to run e2e, "webdriver-manager update" gets called to get the latest chromeDriver from chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com. This happens even though I'm running ng e2e --no-webdriver-update, which causes the run to fail.

How can I specify that I want to use the manually downloaded chromedriver?

Is something like: `ng e2e --driver './chromedriver.exe'` possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try running the e2e tests without downloading the driver:

```
ng e2e -wu false
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
ng e2e --webdriver-update=false
```